# Weird geometry artifacts appearing in Cycles render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry, artifacts

Most frames render something like this:
[image: good render]

But some frames render with strange geometric artifacts, like this:
[image: artifacts render]

What could be causing it? Everything looks fine in the preview render. Problem frames include #2, #15, #18, #19, #20, #23, #24, #29, #48, #52, and more.

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JH-811zHnC1TMx_UGQ5HUolVidJ5ola2/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to have been the ordering of the modifiers on my "water" object. Running the Boolean before the Ocean modifier yields no funny artifacts.